# How to assign a variable to the return statement of a static method?

Tags: java, methods

I cant seem to get the value of the second method please teach me how I'm still a beginner at this. Do I have to use a different variable? And if so how do I assign the return value of that method to the said variable?

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

class JavaChip
{

    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    static double val ;


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        displayLine () ;
        System.out.print ("Enter number of cups of Mocha JavaChip: ");
        val = getMocha( s.nextDouble() ) ;
        System.out.print ("The grams of mocha is: " + val ) ;

        System.out.print ("\nThe grams of sugar is: " + val ) ;
        displayLine () ;
    }

    static double getMocha ( double c )
    {
        return ( 1.215 * c ) ;
    }

    static double getSugar (double c)
    {
        val = ( 0.15 * c ) ;
        return val ;
    }

    static void displayLine()
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]") ;
        System.out.println("[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]") ;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this script?

Comment: the code seems to work for me

Comment: @Naor: you wouldn't call Java code 'a script'.

Comment: @Mike Braun: Sorry, you right, it was automatically. I cannot edit it now..

Comment: Simply put, the program should ask for only one input and with this value it should give two outputs.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the value of a method you have to call it.

```
val = getSugar(num);
```

Using static fields to pass arguments or return values is bad practice.  This is likely to cause confusion and be a cause of subtle multi-threaded bugs.  Its also more complex than just returning the value like you do with `getMocha()`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should saparate your project into two files:
1. File that will include the main function and helper functions of display like displayLine.
2. File that wil represent the business of your project (JavaChip?).

Example:

Program.java:

```
class Program
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        displayLine () ;
        System.out.print ("Enter number of cups of Mocha JavaChip: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        JavaChip jc=new JavaChip();
        double val = jc.getMocha( s.nextDouble()) ;
        System.out.print ("The grams of mocha is: " + val ) ;
        val = jc.getSugar( s.nextDouble());
        System.out.print ("\nThe grams of sugar is: " + val ) ;
        displayLine () ;
    }

    static void displayLine()
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]") ;
        System.out.println("[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]") ;
    }
}
```

JavaChip.java:

```
class JavaChip
{
    public JavaChip()
    {

    }

    public double getMocha ( double c )
    {
        return ( 1.215 * c ) ;
    }

    public double getSugar (double c)
    {
        val = ( 0.15 * c ) ;
        return val ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is 100% correct.Just you are not calling that getSugar(double value) method. Just do the same as you did for getMocha(double value).Then you can get the return value.

Comment: See the professor is just teaching us how to use static in different ways. He says its bad practice to have everything as static but he will teach us that later on. I have to make a number of methods not a number of programs. Sorry. :( What is the num supposed to mean in val = getSugar(num);

Comment: {
        displayLine () ;
        System.out.print ("Enter number of cups of Mocha JavaChip: ");
        val = getMocha( s.nextDouble() ) ;
        System.out.print ("The grams of mocha is: " + val ) ;
  val = getSugar (s.nextDouble());
        System.out.print ("\nThe grams of sugar is: " + val ) ;
        displayLine () ;
    }  When i pass it out as the same as getMocha it asks for an input. basically what i need to do is 1 input, 2 outputs. Im really new to this sorry. :(

Comment: if i am not wrong it is asking you two inputs but you want it should ask one input and with this value it should give two outputs. is it the case ?

Comment: It is simple.just take a double variable for example double d=s.nextDouble(); then call all your methods with the argument d. Hope this will solve your problem.now you can accept my answer.